# Invertibility of the square root of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$. Let $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$).

- The square root of $M$ is defined to be the unique operator $N$ such that
  $$N^2=M.$$
- In this case we write $N=M^{1/2}$

> If $M$ is an invertible operators, is $M^{1/2}$ invertible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $M$ is invertible if and only if there is $\epsilon>0$ such that 
$$\sigma(M)\subset [\epsilon, \infty).$$ Thus $\sigma(M^{1/2})\subset [\epsilon^{1/2},\infty)$ and $M^{1/2}$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is your equivalence well known?

Comment: I think it is. It is in fact easier than it seems. Since $M\ge 0$, we know $\sigma(M)\subset [0,\infty)$. But if $M$ is invertible, we must have $\epsilon =\min \sigma(M) >0$. The other direction is true since $0\not\in \sigma(M)$ means $M$ is invertible.

Comment: According to our answer, the converse is also true. That is if $A^{1/2}$ is invertible, then $A$ is also invertible. Do you agree with me? Thanks.

Comment: Of course, I agree with you!

Comment: I think the equivalence is true only for positive operators. That is it is better to write:'' Let $M$ be a positive operator. Then $M$ is invertible if and only if there is $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$\sigma(M)\subset [\epsilon, \infty).$$ ''
Do you agree with me? Thanks

Comment: @Schüler Yes, you are right! It was implicitly assumed that $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$, as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I think also that if there is $\epsilon>0$ such that
$$\sigma(M)\subset [\epsilon, \infty).$$ Then $$\sigma(M)\subset [0, \infty).$$ So $M$ is positive.

Comment: @Schüler That is also true.

Answer (score 5):

$N(x)=N(y)$ implies $M(x)=N^2(x)=N^2(y)=M(y)$ since $M$ is injective, we deduce that $N$ is injective.

For every $y$, $y=M(x)=N(N(x))$ implies that $N$ is surjective and open (open mapping theorem)

This implies that the inverse of $N$ is continuous $N$ and $N$ is invertible.